# How to assign value from one data class to another data class

Tags: kotlin

I have two data class, and after I assign value to attribute in infoModel, I want assign them to infoArchiveModel which has the same fields, in this case, id, env, description and endpoint in infoArchiveModel should be same as those in infoModel , how can I do that?

```
data class infoModel(
    @Id
    val id: String = "",
    val environment: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val endPoint: String = "",
 
)
```

```
data class infoArchiveModel(
    @Id
    val id: String = "",
    val environment: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val endPoint: String = "",
    val date: String = " "
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data class can also declare a secondary constructor, just like this:

```
data class infoArchiveModel(
    @Id
    val id: String = "",
    val environment: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val endPoint: String = "",
    val date: String = " "
) {
   constructor(model: infoModel): 
        this (model.id, model.environment, model.description, model.endPoint)
}

//use this constructor
val model: infoModel = ...
val archiveModel = infoArchiveModel(model)
```

BTW, class names should always start with a uppercase letter.